# Storing / Extracting images from database with php

Tags: php, image, download, bytea

I am using PHP 5.3.5 and postgreSQL. I am storing and extracting images from database.

For storing i am doing this:

```
 $escaped_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name']));
 $fileModel->setBinary_Data($escaped_data);
```

It's working, i received the image in my database (Bytea field).

The problem is to extract this, i am trying this code to extract my images:

```
$file_info = $fileModel->getBinary_Data($id_file); // This function return the binary_data of the image

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;base64');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_info['_name']);
base64_decode($file_info['binary_data']));
```

When i download the image, i can't see the image...

With echo in:

```
echo base64_decode($file_info['binary_data']);
```

This happen:

http://imageshack.us/f/18/encodez.jpg/

After, i am trying using the function stream_get_contents inside base64_decode, but doens't work.

Someone know how i can download my images with php?

Thanks anyway...

Comment: any reason not to store files in the file-system?

Comment: Yes, i need store images in database because i will implement a OCR system. And the OCR system need read the images in database.

Comment: Someone have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously your custom `getBinary_Data()` returns $file_info['binary_data'] as a resource, not a string.. so either change the function or use `base64_decode(file_get_contents($file_info['binary_data'])));`

And try to use `fclose($file_info['binary_data']);` too then.

P.S. Wasn't there a blob type for binary data in postgre?

Comment: I received the same error message with file_get_contents: "file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given"

Comment: how about `stream_get_contents($file_info['binary_data'])` ?

Comment: it's working, but for download the image is broken. Below my code: echo base64_decode(stream_get_contents($file_info['binary_data']));

Comment: well you have to remove headers and see what it echoes